# Is AFP or SAMBA more secure for external access?

Tags: files, samba

I'm running 12.04 LTS. The title says it all: is AFP or Samba more secure for external access?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking AFP, CIFS/SMB (i.e. SAMBA) and NFS are *not* secure protocols, as they are designed to work inside a local 'trusted' network.

You may have some form of authentication but e.g. the traffic is not encrypted.

If you need secure access you should tunneling the traffic via SSH or even use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "external access." Neither should typically be used except on a local network or VPN-secured WAN, as [Mitch says](https://askubuntu.com/a/328486/22949). In addition to the traffic not being encrypted, these protocols are not designed to be exposed to the entire Internet; a vulnerability that would be considered critical for a service like SSH would often be considered only moderately severe for an SMB/CIFS or AFP implementation. The Windows implementation of SMB/CIFS has had many vulnerabilities, and while Samba on Ubuntu might possibly be more secure, I don't know of any studies that would indicate this.

#### There's another consideration, though.

Windows hardly supports AFP. AFP is supported on OS X, but OS X also supports SMB/CIFS. Provided that you have arranged things for adequate security (for example, if people are accessing it over the Internet, this should only be through an appropriate VPN), you should probably use SMB/CIFS unless you know you won't have any native Windows clients (which seems unlikely, even for an Ubuntu or OS X shop).

#### But this might be a false dilemma.

Multiple services can be enabled to afford access to the same files. You can even configure them with the same restrictions. SMB/CIFS (through Samba on Ubuntu), AFP, NFS, and a variety of other services can run simultaneously.

Of course you shouldn't run additional services without reason--every additional service requires you (or some network administrator working for your organization) to learn how it works, make sure to configure it securely, and provide support, and each additional service somewhat increases your total [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface) as well.

But it's usually better to run more services than to do something with a service that it's not intended for.

In particular, if you need to facilitate access to files over the Internet without a VPN, then even if you already have SMB/CIFS, AFP, and/or NFS set up, you should still use those only on the LAN, and set up an additional, appropriate service for access to files over an unsecured network. SSH, with SFTP, is typically a good service for this.